# json-rpc server via HTTPS using C++?

Tags: c++, web-services, ssl, boost, https

i am planning to build web service on ssl, mostly it will only serve json-rpc query from javascript browser client, but i want to build on server side using C++ with LevelDB backend, what i need is multithreaded server with asynchronous I/O for fast and lightweight server

which library do you recommend?
does boost::asio is enough to build this server?

Comment: Depending on how much code you can afford to write Asio is enough. In fact, no libraries at all could be enough. There's Casablanca for windows and some linux support

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you've got a similar requirement to the one I had just over a year ago.

I tried a few of the asio based HTTP libraries around at the time, but they either lacked SSL support or fell short in other ways, so ended up writing my own. You can find it here: [via-httplib](https://github.com/kenba/via-httplib) I'd be interested to hear what you think of it.

Comment: What does this do for json, or json-rpc?

Comment: @sehe, it does nothing for json, or json-rpc, but my understanding is that uray wants to use LevelDB for that...